# ANTLR4: how to match kv expression with same rule

Tags: token, antlr4

I have the following statement I wish to parse:

key=value

- key: [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*
- value: [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])*

The parser is always confused as key and value have the same rule.

my error grammar:

```
grammar MatchExpr;
prog: stat ;

stat: expr
    ;

expr : kv JOINER kv #joiner
     | kv #condition
     ;

kv: KEY OP VALUE;

JOINER: '&';
KEY : [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z0-9])*;
OP : '=';
VALUE : [a-zA-Z0-9];
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

but another grammar can run :

```
grammar MatchExpr;

prog: stat ;

stat: expr
    ;

expr : kv JOINER kv #joiner
     | kv #condition
     ; kv: KV;

KV: [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])* '=' [a-zA-Z0-9] ([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*;
JOINER: '&'; 
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR will always create a `KEY` token for the input `foo`. No matter if the input is `mu = foo`, then too will there be 2 `KEY` tokens created (with an `OP` token in between).

This is simply how ANTLR's lexer works. The lexer is not "driven" by the parser. It doesn't matter if the parser is trying to match a `VALUE` token, the input `foo` will always be a `KEY` token.

These are the 2 rules by which the lexer creates tokens:

1. create the longest possible match
2. if there are 2 or more lexer rules than match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Because of rule 2, you can see why `KEY` will be created for `foo` and not a `VALUE`.

To fix this, do something like this:

```
kv     : KEY OP value;
value  : KEY | VALUE;

JOINER : '&';
KEY    : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
VALUE  : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ // matches an ID starting with a digit
OP     : '=';
```